# upgrade to 13.10 stalled and restart failed

Tags: upgrade, 13.10, dpkg

I had 13.04 before. In response to a popup to upgrade to 13.10, I clicked yes, and the whole thing went on autopilot overnight. Woke up this morning, and it's stuck at "unpacking X.org". I forced the machine to restart, but failed.

Many had this problem and the suggestion is to execute:

```
sudo dpkg –configure -a
```

But this did not work for me. The error was something like some file missing.

Answer (score 2):

#### If you can boot:

If you want to try to upgrade via the command line, try the instructions [here](http://lawrit.lawr.ucdavis.edu/it-help-center/how-to/upgrading-ubuntu-via-command-line)

In a nutshell, run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to update all packages, then

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

to do the actual update to 13.10

#### Otherwise,

Get your files out (using a Live USB/CD)
and reinstall from a 13.10 Live USB/CD.